# Can i publish a new app by using existing app package name

Tags: android

I want to know that can I publish a new android  app with existing app package name?
 i.e I have a photo editor and its package name is **com.myapps.photoeditor**. now I want to make new version but i will publish VPN. so the new app will totally different. 
VPN will be ok with existing package name **com.myapps.photoeditor**?

plz guide me

Comment: what is exactly it mean?

Comment: The question doesn't appear to include any attempt at all to solve the problem. StackOverflow expects you to [try to solve your own problem first](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592/how-much-research-effort-is-expected-of-stack-overflow-users), as your attempts help us to better understand what you want. Please edit the question to show what you've tried, and show a specific roadblock you're running into with [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) example. For more information, please see [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: If you use the same package name and the same signing certificate this should be possible. For sure you need access to the previous app on the playstore console and the new apk has to be uploaded as update. But in general not recommended from a user perspective.

Comment: Nope. new app = new package name

Comment: This is a very unclear question and a really bad idea. For anyone who struggles to understand: OP wants to update an app to a totally different app (e.g. make a photo editor app become a vpn client app) and is wondering if that is doable maintaining the same package name (which of course is, even though is not a good idea at all).

Answer (score 1):

No, you cannot do this. Package name basically I unique ID for an app. When a package name is associated with an app and it is published over google play this is a unique ID for that app. You cannot publish new app with the same package name but you can update the app.

Comment: Yes what is my question exactly. I will update the existing app but will replace VPN instead of photo editor. can I do this?

Comment: as far as package name is same you can update your complete app. but when you changed packge name then new app will need to be created.

Answer (score 0):

You can't publish two apps with same package name as google consider it as primary key but story doesn't end here. There are two things you can do:

1. you can update your app, here updates mean you can remove existing feature, you can add new feature, you can modify existing feature but you have to handle it properly.
2. But you want the new feature in a separate app then you should change clone your existing code and add new feature and change package name before publishing. **(Not Recommended)**

Answer (score 0):

If you mean by package name as the `applicationId` in `build.gradle`, then the answer is NO. Your new VPN app will overwrite your existing Photo editor app.

If you mean by package name as the package name used by your source codes, then the answer is IT DEPENDS. YES you can use same package name in source code provided that you provide different name for `applicationId`. NO you cannot if you provide the same name for `applicationId` regardless of what you use as the package name used by your source codes.

Know the difference here: https://developer.android.com/studio/build/application-id

Answer (score 0):

- If you want to release a new app with `applicationId` (from *app/build.gradle*) same as any apps before, you can't do it.
- If you want to update an existing app with complete new ideas or feature or name or type, having access to that app's signing keys and developer account, yes you can do it. Just release with version code greater than before